# Can I filter children rather than nested for loop using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I would like to be able to query a set data and display it and it's children.

I would like to see all the parent records but not all of the child records. The child records need to be filtered.

This is the current scenario:

```
Dim query = db.StockLocations.Where(Function(q) q.Id = 1).ToList()

For Each item As StockLocation In query
    For Each ls As LiveStock In item.LiveStocks.Where(Function(x) x.QtyKg > 0 AndAlso x.Issued = False)
        Console.WriteLine("Reel Id: " & ls.Id)
    Next
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

I thought I could use the Linq.Any() on the parents children but it returns every child and not the desired filter children only:

```
Dim linqquery = db.StockLocations.Where(Function(q) q.Id = 1 AndAlso q.LiveStocks.Any(Function(x) x.QtyKg > 0 AndAlso x.Issued = False)).ToList()

For Each item As StockLocation In linqquery
    For Each ls As LiveStock In item.LiveStocks
        Console.WriteLine("Reel Id: " & ls.Id)
    Next
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

Is there a way to do this from the main query rather than query the children separately in the second for loop?

**UPDATE:**
So, as per Rahul Singh's answer, it seems to work oddly. If I use both conditions I get no results. If I use just `x.QtyKg > 0` then it does bring some results but obviously this isn't desired. See the new code and outputs below:

```
Dim query = db.StockLocations.Where(Function(q) q.Id = 12).ToList()

Console.WriteLine("First query (Child filter in for loop)...")
For Each item As StockLocation In query
    Console.WriteLine("Record Count: " & item.LiveStocks.Where(Function(x) x.QtyKg > 0 AndAlso x.Issued = False).Count)
    For Each ls As LiveStock In item.LiveStocks.Where(Function(x) x.QtyKg > 0 AndAlso x.Issued = False)
        Console.WriteLine(ls.Id & " - " & ls.QtyKg & " - " & ls.Issued)
    Next
 Next

 Console.WriteLine("")
 Dim linqquery = db.StockLocations.Where(Function(q) q.Id = 12 AndAlso q.LiveStocks.All(Function(x) x.QtyKg > 0)).ToList()

 Console.WriteLine("Second query (q.LiveStocks.All(Function(x) x.QtyKg > 0))...")
 For Each item As StockLocation In linqquery
    Console.WriteLine("Record Count: " & item.LiveStocks.Count)
    For Each ls As LiveStock In item.LiveStocks
         Console.WriteLine(ls.Id & " - " & ls.QtyKg & " - " & ls.Issued)
    Next
 Next

 Console.WriteLine("")
 Dim linqquery1 = db.StockLocations.Where(Function(q) q.Id = 12 AndAlso q.LiveStocks.All(Function(x) x.QtyKg > 0 AndAlso x.Issued = False)).ToList()

 Console.WriteLine("Second query (q.LiveStocks.All(Function(x) x.QtyKg > 0 AndAlso x.Issued = False))...")
 For Each item As StockLocation In linqquery1
      Console.WriteLine("Record Count: " & item.LiveStocks.Count)
      For Each ls As LiveStock In item.LiveStocks
        Console.WriteLine(ls.Id & " - " & ls.QtyKg & " - " & ls.Issued)
      Next
 Next
```

Output (Key: Id - QtyKg - Issued):
[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project the filtered parent and then filter on child collection like this:-

```
Dim result = stocks.Where(Function(x) x.Id = 2).Select(Function(x)
      Dim filter = x.LiveStocks.Where(Function(z) z.Quantity > 0 AndAlso Not z.Issued)
      Return New Stock With {.Id = x.Id, .LiveStocks = filter.ToList()}
                                                       End Function)
```

Comment: Thank you. There are some inconsistent results. I'll update the question.

Comment: @paulpitchford - Yes sorry for that, `All` won't work here because it expects all conditions to satisfy, so even if 1 child fails it won't take that object. Similarly, `Any` will take all child objects if even 1 object satisfies the condition. You can use my updated code.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.